# Getting segmentation fault for writing a code to find number of pairs in an array

Tags: c++

I am writing a code to find number of pairs in a given array.But i am getting segmentation fault.

I am sorting the given array and then comparing the elements to get pairs.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;


int sockMerchant(int n, vector<int> ar) {
sort(&ar[0], &ar[n]);
int k=1;
int m=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<n;j++){
        if (ar[i]=ar[j])
        k++;
        if(ar[i]!=ar[j])
        i=j;
        m+=k/2;
        break;
    }
}
return m;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> ar;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>ar[i];
    }
    int k = sockMerchant(n,ar);
    cout<<k<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Answer (score 0):

When you say
`vector<int> ar;`
It just creates an empty vector.
So your for loop is basically trying to write to the elements of an empty vector.

```
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>ar[i];
    }
```

You can either:

1. Call `ar.resize(n);` before the for loop

or

2. You can use `vector::push_back` function to let the vector resize dynamically as you enter your values.

```
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int tmp;
        cin>>tmp;
        ar.push_back(tmp);
    }
```

P.S: You don't have to pass `n` to your function. you can use `ar.size()` to get the size of your vector

Comment: One half of this answer is completely wrong, and results in undefined behavior. There are also several other fundamental bugs in the question, that must be pointed out.

Comment: `reserve` is not correct here. Maybe you mean `resize`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yep my bad. Fixed it.